# increasing text size on all text field

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, air

I'm porting my air app to iOS. When I start editing some textfield (with embeded font) characters are getting huge. But if `textField.embedFonts` is set to `false` character size is ok. Maybe someone had met the same problem?

Thank you in advance!!

**UPD:** here's a code used to create text field

```
//tf.embedFonts = true;
tf.embedFonts = false;
tf.selectable = false;
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.multiline = true;
tf.tabEnabled = false;
tf.alwaysShowSelection = true;
tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Tahoma", 16, textColor);
```

**UPD2:** html text of topic is something like the following

```
<P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Tahoma" SIZE="16" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0"      KERNING="0">Topic</FONT></P>
```

Comment: yes! If I set `new TextFormat("Tahoma", 16, textColor)` text is normal. If I set `new TextFormat("MyFont", 16, textColor)` text is huge

Comment: can provide code that you used to set `MyFont`

Comment: maybe it have a default text size

Comment: inside your text is there any html tag

Comment: maybe it's confilict of font size, what if you remove `FACE="Tahoma" SIZE="16"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you use a native iOS font, _sans/_serif for example.